Improving glmm accuracy - what can I do here?
I'm working on a model in R but my validation suggests it's breaking some assumptions - non-normal residuals and heteroscedasticity. My dependent variable is highly skewed, and originally bounded (but continuous) between 5 and 15 but transformed to be bounded between approximately 0-1 (actually more like 0.04 and 0.96, as I've been warned beta distribution doesn't actually like 0s or 1s), and I've been using a beta distribution family. My model currently looks like this:
m1=glmmTMB(score ~ 
             factor(screening)
           + colour
           + factor(treatment)
           + colour:factor(screening)
           + colour:factor(treatment)
           + factor(treatment):factor(screening)
           + (1|id),
           df, family=beta_family(link="logit")
)

For validating I've been using the following:
sresid=resid(m1, type="pearson")
shapiro.test(sresid)
hist(sresid)
fits=fitted(m1)
plot(sresid~fits)

simulateResid <- simulateResiduals(m1) #from DHARMa package
plot(simulateResid)

I'm at a loss where to go after unsuccessfully trying several different family and link combinations that seemed suitable. Of these, the above looks like it's the closest to approaching normal residual distribution, but it's still off.
Data are comma separated below (because I do not know how to insert a table here). Please feel free to copypaste into notepad and save as a .csv file for manipulation.
id,colour,treatment,screening,score
HB002,b,C,1,0.961904761904762
HB003,b,B,1,0.828571428571429
HB005,b,A,1,0.904761904761905
HB006,b,A,1,0.961904761904762
HB007,b,A,1,0.961904761904762
HB008,b,C,1,0.961904761904762
HXB001,b,C,1,0.761904761904762
HXB004,b,C,1,0.895238095238095
HXB005,b,A,1,0.952380952380952
HXB007,b,C,1,0.961904761904762
HXB008,b,A,1,0.904761904761905
HXB013,b,C,1,0.676190476190476
HXB014,b,A,1,0.895238095238095
HXB016,b,A,1,0.961904761904762
HG001,g,B,1,0.961904761904762
HG003,g,B,1,0.676190476190476
HG006,g,B,1,0.961904761904762
HG007,g,C,1,0.885714285714286
HG008,g,A,1,0.961904761904762
HG009,g,C,1,0.961904761904762
HG010,g,B,1,0.961904761904762
HG012,g,C,1,0.961904761904762
HG019,g,A,1,0.961904761904762
HG023,g,A,1,0.961904761904762
HG024,g,B,1,0.847619047619048
HG025,g,A,1,0.961904761904762
HG026,g,C,1,0.961904761904762
HG031,g,B,1,0.961904761904762
HG032,g,A,1,0.961904761904762
HG033,g,B,1,0.961904761904762
HG037,g,C,1,0.961904761904762
HG038,g,A,1,0.619047619047619
HG040,g,A,1,0.952380952380952
HXG001,g,A,1,0.952380952380952
HXG002,g,B,1,0.961904761904762
HXG006,g,C,1,0.961904761904762
HXG009,g,C,1,0.819047619047619
HXG010,g,A,1,0.961904761904762
HXG011,g,C,1,0.961904761904762
HXG012,g,C,1,0.961904761904762
HXG013,g,A,1,0.961904761904762
HXG014,g,A,1,0.961904761904762
HXG015,g,B,1,0.961904761904762
HXG016,g,A,1,0.961904761904762
HXG017,g,B,1,0.961904761904762
HXG018,g,C,1,0.961904761904762
HXG019,g,B,1,0.961904761904762
HXG020,g,C,1,0.952380952380952
HB002,b,C,2,0.495238095238095
HB003,b,B,2,0.761904761904762
HB005,b,A,2,0.961904761904762
HB006,b,A,2,0.895238095238095
HB007,b,A,2,0.923809523809524
HB008,b,C,2,0.219047619047619
HXB001,b,C,2,0.166666666666667
HXB004,b,C,2,0.204761904761905
HXB005,b,A,2,0.4
HXB007,b,C,2,0.171428571428571
HXB008,b,A,2,0.752380952380952
HXB013,b,C,2,0.752380952380952
HXB014,b,A,2,0.247619047619048
HXB016,b,A,2,0.961904761904762
HG001,g,B,2,0.961904761904762
HG003,g,B,2,0.780952380952381
HG006,g,B,2,0.961904761904762
HG007,g,C,2,0.747619047619048
HG008,g,A,2,0.895238095238095
HG009,g,C,2,0.961904761904762
HG010,g,B,2,0.961904761904762
HG012,g,C,2,0.838095238095238
HG019,g,A,2,0.776190476190476
HG023,g,A,2,0.895238095238095
HG024,g,B,2,0.952380952380952
HG025,g,A,2,0.942857142857143
HG026,g,C,2,0.961904761904762
HG031,g,B,2,0.961904761904762
HG032,g,A,2,0.961904761904762
HG033,g,B,2,0.961904761904762
HG037,g,C,2,0.961904761904762
HG038,g,A,2,0.771428571428571
HG040,g,A,2,0.961904761904762
HXG001,g,A,2,0.771428571428571
HXG002,g,B,2,0.961904761904762
HXG006,g,C,2,0.961904761904762
HXG009,g,C,2,0.723809523809524
HXG010,g,A,2,0.961904761904762
HXG011,g,C,2,0.961904761904762
HXG012,g,C,2,0.961904761904762
HXG013,g,A,2,0.961904761904762
HXG014,g,A,2,0.895238095238095
HXG015,g,B,2,0.961904761904762
HXG016,g,A,2,0.780952380952381
HXG017,g,B,2,0.923809523809524
HXG018,g,C,2,0.761904761904762
HXG019,g,B,2,0.961904761904762
HXG020,g,C,2,0.504761904761905
HB002,b,C,3,0.276190476190476
HB003,b,B,3,0.828571428571429
HB005,b,A,3,0.876190476190476
HB006,b,A,3,0.209523809523809
HB007,b,A,3,0.961904761904762
HB008,b,C,3,0.619047619047619
HXB001,b,C,3,0.00952380952380949
HXB004,b,C,3,0.10952380952381
HXB005,b,A,3,0.247619047619048
HXB007,b,C,3,0.580952380952381
HXB008,b,A,3,0.219047619047619
HXB013,b,C,3,0.419047619047619
HXB014,b,A,3,0.142857142857143
HXB016,b,A,3,0.733333333333333
HG001,g,B,3,0.895238095238095
HG003,g,B,3,0.285714285714286
HG006,g,B,3,0.714285714285714
HG007,g,C,3,0.514285714285714
HG008,g,A,3,0.942857142857143
HG009,g,C,3,0.819047619047619
HG010,g,B,3,0.961904761904762
HG012,g,C,3,0.704761904761905
HG019,g,A,3,0.961904761904762
HG023,g,A,3,0.552380952380952
HG024,g,B,3,0.8
HG025,g,A,3,0.933333333333333
HG026,g,C,3,0.695238095238095
HG031,g,B,3,0.961904761904762
HG032,g,A,3,0.847619047619048
HG033,g,B,3,0.876190476190476
HG037,g,C,3,0.961904761904762
HG038,g,A,3,0.885714285714286
HG040,g,A,3,0.904761904761905
HXG001,g,A,3,0.961904761904762
HXG002,g,B,3,0.457142857142857
HXG006,g,C,3,0.857142857142857
HXG009,g,C,3,0.628571428571429
HXG010,g,A,3,0.961904761904762
HXG011,g,C,3,0.895238095238095
HXG012,g,C,3,0.961904761904762
HXG013,g,A,3,0.961904761904762
HXG014,g,A,3,0.695238095238095
HXG015,g,B,3,0.961904761904762
HXG016,g,A,3,0.961904761904762
HXG017,g,B,3,0.761904761904762
HXG018,g,C,3,0.761904761904762
HXG019,g,B,3,0.628571428571429
HXG020,g,C,3,0.59047619047619   


I don't know what you mean by "closest to approaching normal residual distribution" in the context of beta-regression.

Hi Roland. I mean of the variety of families and link functions I tried, the residuals of this one looked more like a normal distribution than the others. If you imagine an error family that is completely inappropriate produces a distribution of residuals that is obviously not normal, then this family and link function produces a distribution that is not as immediately obviously not normal. I hope that helps.

That doesn’t make sense. If you use a distribution family other than the normal distribution, the residuals are not expected to look like a sample from a normal distribution. Maybe have a look at the DHARMa package.
